# All network folders are not visible from macOS

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, network, mojave, smb

I am facing a weird issue with our co-workers' machines who are working on macOS.

We have File Server hosted on windows and end-user are accessing the network path from macOS Mojave. There is no problem with accessing folders and permissions are well configured. Once it is mounted, and people work on some network files for some time, then all shared folders will not appear. It sometimes lists up to A to G and the rests folder disappears. It is very inconsistent.

After unmounting it and mounting back the network, it lists all the folders again.

I have tried:

- Force the Finder to gather all metadata first

  ```
   defaults write com.apple.desktopservices UseBareEnumeration -bool FALSE
  ```
- Speed up browsing on network shares

  ```
  defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores -bool TRUE
  ```
- Disable Directory caching by setting the value to zero in `dir_cache_max_cnt` inside the file `/etc/nsmb.conf`

What would be the other solution that I can try? A restart helps and unmounting network path and mounting back it also resolve which is a temporary workout. I am looking for a permanent solution. Anybody who have faced such an issue? I will appreciate your support or guidance.

Comment: Anyone who can help me or guide me to try any resolution over here. I am limited with all the attempts that I did.